# External IDE for InterSystems Caché

Tags: ide, intersystems-cache

I want to replace the Caché Studio, because it needs to be ran on Windows. Browser based IDE would be most convenient solution for using OS indepedently and mobile.

1. Is there any browser based IDE for use with InterSystems Caché database?...
2. ...Or, is there a way to export Caché class as readable source code like in Studio? I know there's a way to export classes as XML. But that's not the actual source code.

Comment: The user isn't asking for an opinion on something or a recommendation. He just wants to know whether there is any other IDE for Caché at all.

Comment: [This](https://community.intersystems.com/post/how-develop-intersystems-applications-your-favorite-ide) article can help: it introduces several development concepts you can use with external editors (and also plugins for VS Code and IntelliJ IDEA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a browser-based IDE available for Caché programming.  In fact, the only alternative to Caché Studio is George James Software's [Serenji](http://www.georgejames.com/serenji) debugger/editor.

Answer (score 2):

1) I have not come across any browser-based IDE for use with Cache.

2) Yes - we have just released [EnsPlus](http://www.ensplus.com), a commercial Visual Studio extension which allows you to work with ObjectScript code on the file system.

It allows you to export the classes from Cache and work with them as normal files on the file system. However, this is for Windows-based systems only so I am not sure if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The XML *is* the actual source code.

Unfortunately, there is no other option besides Studio, but Intersystems is certainly working on one.

Comment: Slight nitpick - the XML _contains_ the source code but is not actual editable source code, which is what besq was implying.

Comment: the xml representation is one view on the sourcecode. there are others (cdl,udl)